# Unable to install Zenmap due to other dependency on which python-gtk is dependent

Tags: dependencies

I am unable to install the Zenmap in ubuntu 22.04 due to `python-gtk` dependency as `python-gt`k is dependent on python lower version i guess. Please have a look at the image attached for the reference.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1497251/edit) to show us the complete output of your attempt to install.